# How to play an Animation in reverse Direction in AS3.

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, flash-cs5, reverse

I have a button named insta, and by pressing it a movieclip plays. And when pressing other button in the movieclip, the animation Should get reversed. Can anyone give me idea of the code to play in reverse direction.

I have something like this for playing the movieclip

```
stop();

insta.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,startplaying);
function startplaying(event:MouseEvent):void{
play();
```

}

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049788/flash-play-movie-clip-in-reverse

Comment: can you just give me the code as i have some access problem to see that post.

Answer (score 0):

Use Greensock animation solution. 
Class Timelinelite or TimelineMax can play and reverse timelines.

Described here: http://www.greensock.com/timelinemax/