# How to play animation and then play reverse on hover, start playing again until end on hover out using in Adobe Animate (Flash)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, adobe

Sorry this is so specific but I have combed through so many pages and videos and tutorials and can't figure this out.

I have all of my animations within a MovieClip. In the movie clip is also a stage sized white square button with the instance name "btn". Back on the main stage I have a second layer called "actions" with the following code applied to the first (and only) frame. It's not working. At all. (HUGE) tia

```
stop();  // this will stop the movie from playing at the start

btn.addEventListener((MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, playMovie);
btn.addEventListener((MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, stopMovie);

function playMovie(evt:MouseEvent):void {
 play();
}

function stopMovie(evt:MouseEvent):void {
 stop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is when you say `play();` or `stop();` which object are you really commanding? Your `playMovie` function could be in theory used to control many MovieClips at once, in different ways, so be specific with your commands...

```
btn.play(); //start the playback of "btn" MC
btn.stop(); //stop the playback of "btn" MC
```

Also consider using `MOUSE_OVER`/`OUT` instead `ROLL_OVER`/`OUT` etc but whatever works for you.

For reversing you will use `btn.prevFrame();` together with an `ENTER_FRAME` event function. This function reads your Document settings for the FPS. For example, if you set 30 frames-per-sec then whatever instructions you put inside the event function will be processed 30 times per second.

See this other [**`Answer`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2049851/2057709) for advice about reversing the playback of a MovieClip.

Comment: +1
This is the best way to achieve this. @VCOne
You may also use a Timer in association with a Boolean value and use nextFrame and prevFrame if You want to change the speed of the animation. Don't forget the updateAfterEvent in this case.

Comment: So I understood like 50% of these responses.

I updated my code to this but have no idea how to put together the preFrame part. I apologize 'stop();  // this will stop the movie from playing at the start

`btn.addEventListener((MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, playMovie);
btn.addEventListener((MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, stopMovie);

function playMovie(evt:MouseEvent):void {
 play();
}

function stopMovie(evt:MouseEvent):void {
 stop();
}`

Answer (score 2):

**@VC.One** is correct in how you should implement a solve to your issue, however in response to your comment on their answer, I thought I would demonstrate how to implement this fully for you - incase they don't.

```
var removeUpdate = false;
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playMovie); 
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopMovie); 

function playMovie(evt:MouseEvent):void { 

    // Stop rewinding the movie clip and play it  
    if(removeUpdate){
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update); 
        removeUpdate = false;
    }
    // play our button
    btn.play();
}

function stopMovie(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    // stop our button
    btn.stop();
    // ...  and rewind it
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    removeUpdate = true;
}

function update(evt: Event){
   // moves the button movie clip backwards one frame.
   btn.prevFrame();

   // If we have finished rewinding the movie clip, then stop
   if(btn.currentFrame == 1){
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update); 
        removeUpdate = false;
    }
}
```

It is important that you remove the update event because if you don't, the movie will never play again, because it will go one frame forward and then back again every frame due to; `btn.play(); btn.prevFrame();`