# Playing reverse of a MovieClip using ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, movieclip

I have made an animation in Adobe Animate. I want it to be played in reverse. I tried reversing frames but it kinda messes up my animation. So I decided to write a code for it instead.

I tried referring to this post for the code: 
[Flash - Play movie clip in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049788/flash-play-movie-clip-in-reverse)

This makes my animation play reverse whenever my mouse is not on the MovieClip. I am not that well versed with the coding to modify the code to make the animation appear and loop reverse even without hovering the mouse out.

This is the code:

```js
mc.stop();
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mout);

function mover(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stopPlayReverse();
    mc.play();
}

function mout(e:MouseEvent):void {
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse, false, 0, true);
}

function playReverse(e:Event):void {
    if (mc.currentFrame == 1) {
        stopPlayReverse();
    } else {
        mc.prevFrame();
    }
}

function stopPlayReverse():void {
    if (this.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)) {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playReverse);
    }
}
```

I want the `mout` to work on Stage directly and loop, instead of stopping. How do I go about that?

Comment: **this** > **stage** and **stopPlayReverse();** > **mc.gotoAndStop(mc.totalFrames);** Also, first lines, subscribe to **stage**, not to **mc**.

Comment: What do you mean by 'I want the mout to work on the stage directly'?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis I want the event to not be a MouseEvent but just a normal event that runs on stage forever, instead of it being triggered by a mouse action.

Comment: @Organis Thanks that worked. I first got the mc to come to last frame first: mc.gotoAndStop("Last");

Then  added: 
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,mout);

And removed: mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mout);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first got the mc to come to last frame first: mc.gotoAndStop("Last");

Then added:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,mout);
```

And removed:

```js
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mover); 
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mout);
```